# Specialize onOptionsItemSelected in a tabbed activity

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I made a tab activity, menu logic is handled in the main activity because operations are the same.
I need to add a single line of code just for an activity for a specific option...is it possible to specify a general behaviour in the main activity and then, if needed , change something in sub activities?

Comment: isn't TabActivity is deprecated

Comment: oh well my app goes on 2.2+ devices...anyway I could consider changing if it would solve my main problem, otherwise I just lose time

Comment: use the tab in the support v4 samples with fragments. There is one activity with fragments in the content of the tabs.